# Android app getting JSONException

Tags: android, json

my android app throws a JSONException,but i can't figure out why!
i am using a php page for selecting some columns from a MYSQL database and putting them into an array like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name,type,price FROM $tbname";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$jsonarray=array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$jsonarray[]=$row;
    }
$myJSON = json_encode($jsonarray);
echo $myJSON;
```

which results in a JSON like this:

```
[{"name":"sandwich","type":"food","price":"5000"},{"name":"pizza","type":"food","price":"10000"}]
```

But when i try to parse the above JSON in Android Studio it throws JSONException.
my java code:
i have a send data method in class called httpmanager as below:

```
public static String SendData(DataPack pack) throws IOException {
        URL url=new URL(pack.getUri());
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter w=new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        w.write(pack.Encode());
        w.flush();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

then a i have a Asynctask class with a onpostexecute method like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    String jsonStr = s;
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            Toast.makeText(context, "JSON recieved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

i'd appreciate any help on the matter

Comment: post you android code...of json parsing

Comment: Your json seems valid. Post your logcat and parsing code

Comment: How are you trying to parse the JSON? Can you post your Java code?

Comment: sure! i edited my post and added the java code

Comment: `jsonObj.getString("query_result");` how does that relate to your json string?

Comment: @njzk2 i edited the code and its just simple jsonobject now,i still get the exception!
somebody help!
anybody!

Comment: @user3770803 the question remain. Your data is not a json object. I recommend you look at the specs again: http://json.org

Answer (score 0):

How to you parse de JSON?

you need to use the `try/catch` method!

I use something like this:

```
 HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

           //Code for getting objects/arrays


     }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: i do have a try/catch block,but what i dont understand is why is it throwing the exception at all!? the json formatting seems to be correct and i think i'm parsing it just ok,but the exception keeps getting thrown